# Get count by day given time periods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Sample dataframe:

```
    id           start1        end1      start2        end2
0  Bob       2018-11-29  2018-11-30  2018-12-01  2018-12-31
1  James     2018-10-19  2018-10-31         NaT         NaT
2  Jane      2018-04-05  2018-07-12  2018-11-29  2018-11-30
```

Given the above sample dataframe, I'd like to show a frequency count by month and year. Let's assume that during these periods each person (`id`) was "affected" by something. There are up to two time periods for each person (there will always be at least one time period (i.e., `start1` and `end1`), but there may or may not be a second (i.e., `start2` and `end2`)). I want to show how many people were affected by month and year during the entire time frame that anyone was affected.

For example, the above data would result in something like this (not sure if year-month would be same column or multiple—whatever works):

```
   year-month  count
0     2018-04      1
1     2018-05      1
2     2018-06      1
3     2018-07      1
4     2018-08      0
5     2018-09      0
6     2018-10      1
7     2018-11      2
8     2018-12      1
```

My eventual goal would be to look at these across different time periods (e.g., year (all are in 2018 in this example data), month/year, week, etc.).

I am not sure how to go about unpacking these into a single series so I can do a histogram on a single column. I know once I have them in a single column (e.g., `date`) I could do something like:

```
df.groupby(df["date"].dt.month).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

But that would only be by month, and it assumes I already have the dates in a single column.

I could just use `datetime` and keep adding days in a loop if it is between each time frame until I get to the end date, but every time I do something like that I learn that pandas/numpy has a better way. **I'm looking for that better way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using pd.wide_to_long reshape your dataframe first

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

newdf=pd.wide_to_long(df,['start','end'],i='id',j='drop')
newdf=newdf.apply(pd.to_datetime)
newdf=newdf.dropna()
newdf.start=newdf.start.values.astype('datetime64[M]')
newdf.end=newdf.end+MonthEnd(0)
newdf
                start        end
id    drop                      
Bob   1    2018-11-01 2018-11-30
James 1    2018-10-01 2018-10-31
Jane  1    2018-04-01 2018-07-31
Bob   2    2018-12-01 2018-12-31
Jane  2    2018-11-01 2018-11-30
```

---

Then we using `date_range`

```
l=[pd.date_range(x,y,freq='M',closed ='right').strftime('%Y-%m') for x ,y in zip(newdf.start,newdf.end)]
pd.Series(np.concatenate(l)).value_counts()
2018-11    2
2018-05    1
2018-12    1
2018-04    1
2018-06    1
2018-10    1
2018-07    1
dtype: int64
```